# jQuery send empty data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have jQuery script to send data from one php to another one.

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
jQuery(".button").click(function(){
$.ajax({
            url         : "content_articles.php",
            type        : 'POST',
            data        : {'mark': ButtonValue}
        }).done(function(response){
            alert(response);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('FAILED! ERROR: ' + errorThrown);
        });
});
```

});

It should take button's value and send it. The value is right, checked with "some debug" alert. But all I have in the end is alert 'FAILED! ERROR: ' with no error message.

On the other side i use

```
$rowid=$_POST['mark'];
```

It is empty of course...

The rest of content_articles

```
<?php
$rowid=$_POST['mark'];
/*echo $_POST['mark'];
exit;*/
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$mysqli = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$MySQLSelectedDB = mysql_select_db('content', $mysqli);
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$last =mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
if($rowid==""){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = ".$last['id'];
}
else
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='".$rowid."'";
}
$result = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `dataType: json` instead of `ContentType : 'application/json',`

Comment: Done! Hope my answer help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you ajax replace `alert('succesful');` by `alert(response);`.

Let's check if MARK is arriving ok, put next 3 lines at the top of your code :

```
$rowid=$_POST['mark'];
echo $_POST['mark'];
exit;
```

Let's shorten your code :

```
$rowid=$_POST['mark'];
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$mysqli = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$MySQLSelectedDB = mysql_select_db('content', $mysqli);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='".$rowid."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['SOME_COLUMN'];
```

You replace "SOME_COLUMN" by a column in table "news".

let's check if there are results from your query, replace the last line by this one:

```
echo mysql_num_rows( $result );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use next

```
    var ButtonValue = $(this).attr('value');
     // check here that your ButtonValue is not empty, you can call alert(Buttonvalue); to sure that this var is not empty and receive value from clicked element

    $.post('content_articles.php', { mark:ButtonValue }, function(data){
        alert(data); // to show what the resposne from script
    });
```

Make sure in console of browser that your PHP script is available and server not return any error (like 404 or 500 and etc)